# Reshaping data table to make column names into row names

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I have a `data.table` in `R`

```
> dt
  SAMPLE   junction count
1: R1        a       1
2: R2        a       1
3: R3        b       1
4: R3        a       1
5: R1        c       2
```

Now I want to "reshape" the data table to form a `data frame` `m` (basically junction by sample matrix with index value to be corresponding count value). Also, observe that for `(SAMPLE,junction)` pairs that don't exist in `dt`, I am assuming the corresponding `count` value to be `zero`. 
Could someone help me how to achieve this?

```
> m
      R1   R2   R3
  a    1    1    1
  b    0    0    1
  c    2    0    0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `dcast` from `data.table` changes the dataset from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(dt, junction~SAMPLE, value.var='count', fill=0)
#   junction R1 R2 R3
#1:        a  1  1  1
#2:        b  0  0  1
#3:        c  2  0  0
```

If you need a matrix output

```
library(reshape2)
acast(dt, junction~SAMPLE, value.var='count', fill=0)
#   R1 R2 R3
#a  1  1  1
#b  0  0  1
#c  2  0  0
```

Or `xtabs` from `base R`

```
 xtabs(count~junction+SAMPLE, dt)
```

Comment: What do you do when you the column `junction` is the row index of the dataframe? Or when you have the `m` dataframe and you want the rows to be the columns and the columns to be the rows.

Comment: @capm with `data.table`, when you create the data.table with `setDT`, there is an option to keep the row.names `setDT(dt, keep.rownames = TRUE)` if that is what you meant

Comment: I was thinking more something like `acast(m, colnames(m) ~ row.names(m))` to get `a <- data.frame(c(1,1,1), c(0,0,1), c(2,0,0), row.names = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3'))` with `colnames(a) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')`.

Comment: @capm What is your expected for the 'a' dataset

Comment: From `m <- data.frame(c(1,0,2), c(1,0,0), c(1,1,0), row.names = c('a', 'b', 'c'))` with `colnames(m) <- c('R1', 'R2', 'R3')`, using something like `acast(m, colnames(m) ~ row.names(m))`, I want to get the dataframe: `a <- data.frame(c(1,1,1), c(0,0,1), c(2,0,0), row.names = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3'))` with `colnames(a) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')`.

Comment: @capm Isn't this just `t(m)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200356/discussion-between-capm-and-akrun).

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach using `spread` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

spread(dt, SAMPLE, count, fill=0)
#   junction R1 R2 R3
#1:        a  1  1  1
#2:        b  0  0  1
#3:        c  2  0  0
```

Or old school solution with `reshape` from `stats`:

```
reshape(dt, timevar='SAMPLE', idvar=c('junction'), direction='wide')
#   junction count.R1 count.R2 count.R3
#1:        a        1        1        1
#2:        b       NA       NA        1
#3:        c        2       NA       NA
```

**Data:**

```
dt = structure(list(SAMPLE = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R3", "R1"), junction = c("a", 
"a", "b", "a", "c"), count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)), .Names = c("SAMPLE", 
"junction", "count"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x05e924a0>)
```